# Validate the fields belonging to other/imported model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a model called user and another model called student.

Neither of them have a relation to each other defined in models but the form for user has to post some of the data to student as well.

I want to validate all the fields related to student.

I did:

```
$impstudent = ClassRegistry::init('Student');
```

It gets all the fields but I want to know how to invoke the validate for student model from `users_controller`.

Comment: You're using both Cakephp 2.0 AND CakePHP 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply validate it before saving both models or whatever fits your requirements:

```
    $Model->set($yourData);
    $Model->validates();
```

Also see http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelvalidates